# Integrating Isotope with BBQ hash history

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-bbq

I know it's a popular question but I'm struggling a little with the tutorial on the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) site to develop my current Isotope to use [BBQ hash history](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html).

I am essentially trying to add BBQ hash history to my current set up so I can link directly to the filtered content.

This is my jQuery code so far, which works perfectly.

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $container = jQuery('.wwd-content-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.each-wwd-content',
            filter: '.corporate'
        });
    });
    jQuery('.wwd-filters a').click(function () {
        jQuery('a.active-filter').removeClass('active-filter');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active-filter');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And I have changed my filter navigation from:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo esc_attr( $page_class ) ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="#filter=.<?php echo esc_attr( $page_class ) ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
```

I am using Wordpress hence the $page_class variables etc — but don't spend too much time on that.

Thanks and any help would be most appreciated.
R

**UPDATE**

This is what I have so far...

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $container = jQuery('.wwd-content-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.each-wwd-content',
            filter: '.corporate'
        });
    });
    jQuery('.wwd-filters a').click(function () {
        jQuery('a.active-filter').removeClass('active-filter');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active-filter');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.wwd-filters a').click(function(){
          // get href attr, remove leading #
      var href = jQuery(this).attr('href').replace( /^#/, '' ),
          // convert href into object
          // i.e. 'filter=.inner-transition' -> { filter: '.inner-transition' }
          option = $.deparam( href, true );
      // set hash, triggers hashchange on window
      $.bbq.pushState( option );
      return false;
    });
    jQuery(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ){
      // get options object from hash
      var hashOptions = $.deparam.fragment();
      // apply options from hash
      $container.isotope( hashOptions );
    })
      // trigger hashchange to capture any hash data on init
      .trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've gotten rid of the value for your variable `selector`, since your a tag no longer has an attribute of `data-filter`. If you set a breakpoint to get the value of `selector`, you'll see it returns `undefined` instead of something like `.corporate` or any of your other values. This means Isotope doesn't filter anything anymore.

Have a good look over the documentation for this, linked below.
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/hash-history-jquery-bbq.html

Your click event function should look more or less like the documentation, particularly the section titled '*jQuery script*'. This function grabs the selector from the href value, filters your instance of Isotope, and then pushes it through BBQ hash history management.

I would make sure you have a function bound to `hashchange` as well, exactly what is written in the documentation. It's very important to make sure you are hooking into BBQ's `hashchange` event to make your filtered content bookmarkable.

**UPDATE**

You've got two functions hooked up on click. You really only need the second one which will then fire the Isotope filter from the `hashchange` event.

Have a look at the following code and compare to your earlier example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HWwa4/1/

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I have updated my code above with how I felt it should go down, but I'm still missing something. I get these errors:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fragment' of undefined:446
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'deparam'

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or test environment so I can see what's happening?